# Batch file to replace content

Tags: batch-file

I ran below code in batch file and at the end XML file opened in notepad++ format, now I want to search and replace the content of file and make a copy of the original file... Can you please help?

```
XCOPY "C:\Program Files (x86)\CAST\7.3\WARS\*.*war" "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps"
net start "Tomcat7"
net start "CastStorageService2"
TIMEOUT /T 60

REM Open all the static content files
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\CAST-AAD\META-INF\context.xml"
```

Comment: I would suggest doing this with powershell. It will make your life easier.

Comment: @Ajay I don't have understood the task. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34415941/edit) your question and explain it better. Do you want to copy the file `context.xml` from command line and also opened in Notepad++? Or do you want to replace something in `context.xml`? What is the search string? What is the replace string? What does `context.xml` contain? Should the replace be done in Notepad++ or from within batch file? What about [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/)

Comment: ok.. in simple I want to search and replace string in context.xml using batch file.. the content in context.xml is [Dashboard Schema]  and want to replace by ajay_measure

Comment: any help will be appreciated !